# How do I use Datanucleus with multiple Eclipse projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, classpath, datanucleus

I need an Eclipse expert. I have one project referencing another in the classpath to make use of all the classes and data objects. The first app is an AppEngine project. The second app is just a plain old Java command line application to import. I run into this error when it executes this line in the code. The second project is set to import the first project. I tried to exclude 3 Datanucleus JARs from the build path of one project, but then it complains that the classes are not enhanced. I also tried adding AppEngine and removing AppEngine to the second 'import' project.

#### Error

> Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Users/Chloe/Documents/Onix/mwv-pic/war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Users/Chloe/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0_587203511_win32_win32_x86_64/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.6/appengine-java-sdk-1.8.6/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar."

#### Code

```
instance = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
```

#### Project Properties

[image: Imgur]

#### Version

datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to go into the first project, view Project Properties > Build Path > Libraries > Delete datanucleus-core.jar, datanucleus-api-jdo.jar, datanucleus-api-jpa.jar. Those three are already in the AppEngine library. If you scroll further down and expand 'AppEngine SDK' group, you will see them also listed in there. So they did not have to be listed twice. I have no idea why the first app worked without any problems but it fails to work if you import the project into another project (put it on the classpath).